# SQL Server READ_COMMITED_SNAPSHOT inside of trigger

Tags: sql-server, locking

Due to repeated deadlocks caused by temporary heavy load (around 10 sec.), I wanted to change the isolation level of our database form READ_COMMITED to READ_COMMITED_SNAPSHOT.

I have tried to read as much as possible about it, but there is one thing I am absolutely unsure of:
How will this affect triggers inserting data and then reading the ID of the inserted row?

There are 2 possibilities here (assuming that there are rows with lower IDs present) and assuming those 2 rows are inside a trigger on some other

1)

```
Insert into table (ID) value (3);
Select Top 1 ID from table order by ID desc;
```

2)

```
Insert into table (ID) value (3);
Select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

In theory these should be fine, but Id'd like confirmation. Thanks

Comment: I'd look at the deadlock graph and try to speed up the slow transactions before just changing the isolation level.

Comment: I'd like that too, unfortunately this is (at least to my abilities) not possible due to a lot of data being genareted across multiple tables on the insertion of single row in a certain table. The generation joins multiple other tables to generate the desired data.

Comment: How do you get a deadlock graph? O_o

Comment: @serge, run a trace in the profiler (pick the blank template), select the deadlock graph event, and on the new tab that appears (Events Extraction Settings), save each (check save deadlock XML events separately) in its own file. Open this file in an xml viewer and it will be easy to tell what is happening. Each process is contained, with a stack of procedure calls, etc. and all locks are in there too, so you can be sure what is causing the deadlock.

Let this trace run until the deadlock happens again, info is only recorded when a deadlock happens, so not much overhead.

Comment: How to Track Down Deadlocks Using SQL Server 2005 Profiler: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-track-down-deadlocks-using-sql-server-2005-profiler/

Comment: Here is an article on finding deadlocks without profiler.  SQL 2008 and up though I'm afraid.  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/deadlock/65658/

Comment: Use either `Scope_Identity()` or an `OUTPUT` clause to get the identity assigned to new rows.  They do not suffer from the race conditions that a `SELECT` allows.

Comment: @HABO, please post that as an answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either [Scope_Identity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) or an [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get the identity assigned to new rows. They do not suffer from the race conditions that a SELECT allows.  The isolation level should not present a problem.

`OUTPUT` is a good thing to have in your bag of tools for a variety of reasons.  It works for `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` and `MERGE` statements.  It isn't limited to a single row.  It does allow capture of multiple columns, not just an identity value.

Do not use `@@IDENTITY`, for it gets values from the dark side.  (Unless you need a source of unpredictable values.)  `IDENT_CURRENT()` is also rarely useful.

Comment: While there is already an `inserted` table in my inserttrigger, how do I you `output`? Doesn't that conflict with the existing `inserted` table?

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno - The `inserted` and `deleted` tables ([Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx).) reflect the action of the statement that caused the trigger to fire.  An `OUTPUT` clause on a statement allows you to explicitly direct the columns of your choice _from the containing statement_ to a table.  There is no conflict.